# Win Powershell Associate file type with default app

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon Folks,

I have been trying without success to create a Win Powershell script that associates a specific file extension .dgn to a specific cadd application.  The reason for this is that after multiple installation of various cadd software the most recent app becomes the one associated with the cadd file extension which usually not the one we want.

After some web searches it is my understanding is that I need to first find what the correct name of the default app I want it to be associated with.  So I used `cmd /c assoc .dgn` to find that the app is called **Bentley MicroStation Design**

Then you can link that default application to an executable, with something like:  `cmd /c ftype Bentley Microstation Design=ustation.exe`

Unfortunately what I have created doesn't work:

```
cmd /c assoc .dgn=Bentley Microstation Design
cmd /c ftype Bentley Microstation Design="%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Bentley\MicroStation V8i (SELECTseries)\MicroStation\ustation.exe" %1 %*
```

But I get an error stating *"File Type 'Bentley Microstation Design="%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Bentley\MicroStation V8i (SELECTseries)\MicroStation\ustation.exe' not found or no open command associated with it."*

It does exist:
[image]

So it does exist, but does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks,

Comment: [The FileType should always be created before making a File Association with ASSOC](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html).

Comment: Moreover, I'd use a *file type* without space e.g. `Bentley.MicroStation.Design` instead of `Bentley MicroStation Design`…